# Importing corrupted photos in Shotwell on MSI Modern 14 (Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04)

Tags: 19.10, sd-card, shotwell, msi

When I use a SanDisk micro SD (64 gb exFat formatted), every import in Shotwell is fine.

But, when I switch to a SanDisk 32 gb SD card, every photo that I try to import is corrupted (parts of the photos are switched, grey/green areas etc.).

What I tried to do is to see if other computers would do the same, and turns out only MSI does that with SD card - HP Pavilion under Ubuntu 20.04 works great, MacBook Pro 2014 reads every photo from SD card fine, HP ProBook on Windows 10 Pro also reads it fine.

I tried to format it multiple times, with different settings - MSI still does not perform clear import. Even after I tried to upgrade to 20.04 the problem is the same.

If anyone had the same issue, what was the way to fix this?